# PHP Login Issue without SQL Database

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to create a login page and I am having some troubles. I cannot get this code not to return false even though I know I have the right password in my .txt document (It's just hashed though).

Here's my PHP file that I can not stop getting not to return False:

```
<?php
$file1 = 'userlist.txt';
$file2 = 'passlist.txt';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $user = trim($_POST["usermail"]);
    $pass = trim($_POST["password"]);
}

$hashedPass = "";

$arr1 = file($file1);
$arr2 = file($file2);
$userKey = array_search($user, $arr1);


if ($userKey != false) {
    reset($arr2);
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $userKey; $x++) {
        next($arr2);
        if ($x == $userKey) {
            $hashedPass = current($arr2);
        }
    }
    echo $hashedPass;
}

if (password_verify($pass, $hashedPass)) {
    header("Location: worked.html"); //change this to direct user to market
}
else {
    /*header("Location: index.html"); //change this to direct user back to login page with error prompt*/
    print $pass;
    print $hashedPass;
    echo '<br>Invalid pass.';
    return false; 
}
?>
```

Also, if you can think of anything I should have in my code, please let me know. 
Thanks so much.

Edit: Updated what I have for my code right now. Still returning False.

Answer (score 0):

Since `unHash` is a `function`, it is not getting executed (it is not called from what I can see), so `$hashedPass` is not getting set.  In the future, try adding some debug statements (e.g. just print out `$pass` and `$hashedPass` before the `return false;`).

Comment: So I should do: 
if (password_verify($pass, $hashedPass.unHash())) { ? That's not working for me.

Comment: There are other issues but I think they all go away if you just remove `function unHash(){` and the closing `}`.  Unless you need the function `unHash` for a call from somewhere, this might be your best approach.  Plus that debug statement.

Comment: I did that, and it still is returning False.

Comment: At this point, you need to debug.  Either use a debugger (not familiar with what is available for PHP) or just add `echo` statements to your code to see where is stops performing as you expect.

Comment: It looks like the hashed password won't get out of the `if ($userKey != false)` statement.

Comment: By "get out of it", do you mean `$userKey` appears to be false?  What are `$user` and `$arr1` getting set to?  btw, feel free to accept my answer if you feel it at least solved your initial problem...

Comment: What exactly do you get as response? A blank page?

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark: You have turned off error messages and only get a blank page instead of a redirect when entring a right login combination?

If that is the case, you might use the following code:

```
<?php
$file1 = 'userlist.txt';
$file2 = 'passlist.txt';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $user = trim($_POST["usermail"]);
    $pass = trim($_POST["password"]);
}

$hashedPass = "";

$arr1 = file($file1);
$arr2 = file($file2);
$userKey = array_search($user, $arr1);


if ($userKey != false) {
    reset($arr2);
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $userKey; $x++) {
        next($arr2);
        if ($x == $userKey) {
            $hashedPass = current($arr2);
        }
    }
  //  echo $hashedPass;
}

if (password_verify($pass, $hashedPass)) {
    header("Location: worked.html"); //change this to direct user to market
}
else {
    /*header("Location: index.html"); //change this to direct user back to login page with error prompt*/
    print $pass;
    print $hashedPass;
    echo '<br>Invalid pass.';
    return false; 
}
?>
```

The reason your code fails is the echo statement, which is executed before the header-redirect. It´s not allowed to have any output before an header-redirect. (more about this behaviour: [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php))